# Find Control Text (ASP.NET/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to pull the text value of the label that is dynamically populated by a SQL database.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

***ASP.NET***

```
<asp:Label ID="PlatformName" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PlatformName") %>' runat="server" />
```

***C# Code Behind (Which gives me the object, not the string value in the label)***

```
string strPlatform = GameGrid.Rows[counter].FindControl("PlatformName").ToString()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FindControl will return a control (of type Control), so you will need to cast it to a Label to access the Text property.

Try:

```
Label lbl = GameGrid.Rows[counter].FindControl("PlatformName") as Label;
if (lbl != null)
    strPlatform = lbl.Text;
```